# Codeigniter: Sum contents of the records in a field

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, sum

I am fetching some information from mysql database and I am displaying it using the following script(I am using Codeigniter).

**Models**

```
    public function sum($field, $table, $userfield, $username)
    {
        return $this->db->query("SELECT SUM($field) FROM $table WHERE $userfield = '$username'");
    }
```

**Controller**

```
    public function save(){
        $data = array(
        'sum_simpan' => $this->user_m->sum('besar_simpanan', 'simpanan', 'id', $this->session->userdata('username'))->result()
    ); }
```

**View**

```
    <div class="info-a">
        <p>Total Simpanan Anda</p>
        <h3><?php  
           foreach ($sum_simpan as $row) {
            echo $row->besar_simpanan;
           }
        ?>
            </h3>
    </div>
```

I want to do is sum the contents of a field, and display it in the view.
However I get an error

`A PHP Error was encountered`
`Severity: Notice`

`Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$besar_simpanan`

`Filename: anggota/simpanan.php`

`Line Number: 14`

---

Would you please kindly show me how to do it.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: This problem says query did not return any data

Comment: where you called your view file?It seems you did not passed the value at your view.

Answer (score 0):

Change your model like this

```
public function sum($field, $table, $userfield, $username)
    {
        return $this->db->query("SELECT SUM($field) as total FROM $table WHERE $userfield = '$username'");
    }
```

also the view

```
<h3>
<?php  
    foreach ($sum_simpan as $row) {
            echo $row->total;
     }
?>
</h3>
```